# IEnumerable of Claims for each items terminates with sql error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is the code i used to get claims from OWIN context.

```
            IOwinContext ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            ClaimsPrincipal user = ctx.Authentication.User;
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;

            string cm="";
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in claims)
            {
                cm = item.Value;
                if(i==2) break;
                i = i + 1;
            }
```

If I remove the 'break' in foreach statement then it will lead to the strange and falsely claiming an SQL error as 'unable to connect to SQL Server' but the fact is i didnt use any DB. Also please guide me to get a value at index in the above IEnumerable.

Comment: If you try to access from the index, for sample: `string cm = claims.ElementAt(2).Value;`.

Comment: When using ElementAt the following error occured: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt' and no extension method 'ElementAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)